# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#app" returned null

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

Please help me figure this out. Been for a while trying to figure this out but can't make it work. Where should I put my  `<script src="{% static 'js/custom-vue.js' %}"></script>` to be able to resolve the error shown in the image below? Thank you.

**master.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profile</title>  
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/vue.global.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/custom-vue.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    
</head> 

<body>

    <div class="container">

        {% block content %}
        
        {% endblock %}

    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

**profile.html**

```
{% extends 'users/master.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Profile Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Profile</h2>
<p>ID: {{ user.id }}</p>
<p>Username: {{ user.username }}</p>
<p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
<p>First name: {{ user.first_name }}</p>
<p>Last name: {{ user.last_name }}</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></p>

  <div class="container-fluid">

   <div id="app">
    
        <button @click="showModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-calendar-event"></i> New Event</button>&nbsp;
        <button @click="showCalModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-calendar-check"></i> Calendar Category</button>&nbsp;
        <button @click="showDivModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-person-square"></i> Division</button>&nbsp;
      
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add event</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Event title" required></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_location" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" required></p>
                    <p><select name="division_id" class="form-control form-select" aria-label="Default select example" v-model="selectedDivisionId" @change="onDivisionChange">
                      <option value="0" selected>Select Division</option>
                      {% for val in divisionList %}
                      <option value="{{ val.id }}">{{ val.division_name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select></p>
                    <p><select name="calendar_id" class="form-control form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                      <option selected>Select Calendar</option>
                      {% for val in calendarList %}
                      <option value="{{ val.id }}">{{ val.calendar_name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select></p>
                    <p><input type="datetime-local" name="whole_date_start" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Start" v-model="startdate" @change="updateDateFields" required></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_day_start" class="form-control" placeholder="Day Start"  v-model="dayStart" required></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_month_start" class="form-control" placeholder="Month Start"  v-model="monthStart" required></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_year_start" class="form-control" placeholder="Year Start"  v-model="yearStart" required></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="event_time_start" class="form-control" placeholder="Time Start"  v-model="timeStart" required></p>
                    <p><input type="datetime-local" name="whole_date_end" class="form-control" placeholder="Event End" v-model="enddate" required></p>
                    <p><textarea name="event_desc" class="form-control" id="id-desc" placeholder="Add a description"></textarea></p>
                    <p><textarea name="participants" class="form-control" id="id-participants" placeholder="Participants"></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="file" name="file_attachment" class="form-control" ></p>
              
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
       </div> <!-- end of app  -->
      
    <hr>

    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

**custom-vue.js**

```
// In your custom-vue.js
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
  return {
    startdate: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    dayStart: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    monthStart: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    yearStart: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    timeStart: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    enddate: '', // Initialize with an empty string
    selectedDivisionId: null, // Initialize selectedDivisionId with null
  };
},
created() {
  // Initialize the date property with the current date and time in Manila, Philippines (UTC+8)
  const now = new Date();
  const manilaOffset = 8 * 60; // UTC+8 offset for Manila
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + manilaOffset);
  const isoDate = now.toISOString().slice(0, 16); // Format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"
  this.startdate = isoDate;
  this.enddate = isoDate;
  // Set the default selected to "Select Division"
  this.selectedDivisionId = 0;
 
},
methods: {
  showModal() {
    // Show the Bootstrap modal by selecting it with its ID and calling the 'modal' method
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  },
  showDivModal() {
    // Show the Bootstrap modal by selecting it with its ID and calling the 'modal' method
    $('#myDivModal').modal('show');
  },
  showCalModal() {
    // Show the Bootstrap modal by selecting it with its ID and calling the 'modal' method
    $('#myCalModal').modal('show');
  },
  onDivisionChange() {
    // Show an alert with the selected division ID
    //alert(`Selected Division ID: ${this.selectedDivisionId}`);
    console.log(this.selectedDivisionId);
  },
  updateDateFields() {
    // split the datetime value and update individual date fields
    const datetimeValue = this.startdate;
    const [date, time] = datetimeValue.split('T'); // Format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"
    const [year, month, dayStart] = date.split('-');
    // Update the date fields
    this.dayStart = day;
    this.monthStart = month;
    this.yearStart = year;
    this.timeStart = time;
   },
  },
});
```

**settings.py**

```
 # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'calendars/static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'divisions/static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'employees/static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'events/static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'users/static'),
# Add paths for other app static directories as needed
]
```

**error:**
[image]

**folder structure**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the order of execution i.e. extending from master.html, you need to have these at the end of the `<body>`

```
<script src="{% static 'js/vue.global.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/custom-vue.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: when i move it at the end of the body, it says - GET http://localhost:8000/static/js/custom-vue.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). My custom-vue.js is located in C:\Users\Jun\python-project\dticalendar\staticfiles\js

Comment: Well as it says, it's looking at 'static/js...' and your file is in 'staticfiles/js...' either you have put it in the wrong directory, or you need to look at your jsconfig.json